# Verilog truth tables

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, system-verilog, max10

I am starting in verilog, I am very confused with truth tables, how do I do it in verilog using "if-else", my instructor introduced us to the topic with the following example:

[image]

after seeing that, we have to do the following exercise:

[image]

I am very confused, what I am looking for is a brief explanation and if possible a brief example of how to solve it, I don't want you to solve my task, but help me to understand it, thanks in advance.

as a side note, I am using Quartus prime 20.1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework with no attempt to solve it.

Comment: It looks like you were given a brief example. What specifically about that example is confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDL and verilog almost *precipitated* out of thin air around the same time -- the early 1980's -- by completely different actors but for what in hindsight looks like similar reasons. Their purposes were more about documenting digital ASIC and/or logic systems, than much else. It wasn't long before the idea of trying to simulate them came about (a year or two later.) Only later did automated synthesis to FPGA or wafer masks come about. Digilent has [this reference about the history of verilog](https://digilent.com/reference/learn/fundamentals/digital-logic/verilog-hdl-background-and-history/start). It's worth a moment's skimming just to pick up some of the context.

To keep it simple, there are mainly two kinds of **always@** blocks: combinatorial and sequential. You can easily tell which is which by just noting if the keywords \$posedge\$ or \$negedge\$ appear as adverbs in the sensitivity list. If so, then it's sequential logic (possibly with an asynchronous event of some kind.) If not, it's combinatorial.

The sensitivity list tells the simulator (or synthesizer) what to examine for a change before bothering with the enclosed block behavior description(s). For combinatorial code.

A mux is combinatorial logic, so if you look at the sensitivity list you should **not** expect to see **always@** with a sensitivity list showing either \$posedge\$ or \$negedge\$. And you don't. That's a good thing. Often, in the case of combinatorial logic, you will see **always@( * )** rather than a specific list. It's probably safer, at least when first starting out, to do it that way. It just means that "if anything changes" the block should be considered and re-evaluated. (It will infer the sensitivity list for you.) And that's usually what you want. But you can be pedantic and just list the specific inputs that affect the block, too. It's up to you.

Since you are working on combinatorial questions, I'll avoid talking about the case where you see \$posedge\$ or \$negedge\$ showing up in the sensitivity list.

Now, in your case you have two selection bits (indicated as a 2-bit wire, so to speak) and four output bits (indicated as a 4-bit wire.) You should be able to figure out what to give for the line that includes the **always@** statement. Do you know how to specify multi-bit wires? Can you discuss how you'd imagine writing the block describing the desired behavior whenever either of the two selection bits change? Just write it out in English (please, no Spanish) as if you were trying to describe it. That alone might take you pretty close to where you want to be.

Comment: "precipitated out of thin air " is a major understatement. A much more accurate history of Verilog is presented by some of its authors: https://semiengineering.com/verilog-hdl-and-its-ancestors-and-descendants/

Comment: @dave_59 That's 90 pages!! But I'll read it. ;) And thanks!

Comment: @dave_59 Crap! That's good reading! Halfway through it and it's getting very good to read. Thanks, again!